# JDK 8 to JDK 7 on mac OSX

Tags: java

I was earlier using jdk 8 but now for a project I require jdk 7. I have a mac so how do I change my jdk from 8 to 7. 
I can see all the jdk installed on my mac from library-->java-->java virtual machines.
Also I have tried going to system preferences-->java control pannel-->java . This only shows the JRE does not show JDK's installed on mac so I cannot change that from here.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using an IDE of any sort?

Comment: Gimby's answer should be fine, but you can also use any installed JDK/JRE by simply pointing to the directory.  No need to tell the entire system to use it if you only need to compile a specific project.

Comment: Thanks @peter. I have switched on to Eclipse and now I am able to select specific JDK I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than downgrading the JDK, you are free to compile Java 7 compatible classes for this one project using your existing Java 8 JDK.

```
javac -source "7" -target "7" <other compile arguments here>
```

if you use an automated build tool such as ANT or Maven or an IDE you can simply configure these properties once (you'll have to check the documentation how to do that for your specific development tools).

The javac documentation has more information on the usage of these flags:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html

Comment: Thanks Gimby I was trying to run the code from command line so I wasn't sure how to switch the JDK. I have moved to eclipse for now and there it gives me option to select the specific JDK i want. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Indeed; and you can then still configure a JDK 8 but configure it to produce java 7 compatible classes for the entire workspace should you not want to go through the hassle of installing multiple runtimes/JDKs. Window->preferences->java->compiler, set to compliance level 1.7.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Gimby's solution

or

if you want / need the JDK 7 of java here is the download page :

> http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html

read this in order to choose your version of Java :

> **What is the difference between a Java CPU (7u79) and PSU (7u80) release?**
>
> Java SE Critical Patch Updates (CPU) contain fixes to security vulnerabilities and critical bug fixes. Oracle strongly recommends that all Java SE users upgrade to the latest CPU releases as they are made available. Most user should choose this release.
> Java SE Patch Set Updates (PSU) contain all of the security fixes in the CPUs released up to that version, as well as additional non-critical fixes. Java PSU releases should only be used if you are being impacted by one of the additional bugs fixed in that version.

Then select the download link for mac.

Hope this help